# Fancybox/Essential Grid: The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

When I first load the page and first click the link the pop up works. But when I tried it for the second time it doesn't work. I think there's something to do with the JS, but I don't know how.

```
<div id="esg-grid-9-1" class="esg-grid">
<a class="eg-tm-recent-posts-01-element-0 eg-post-53 esgbox" href="#inline1" style="color:#333">Click to pop</a>
</div>

<div id="inline1" class="" style="display:none;min-width:400px;max-width:800px !important;padding:20px !important;">
Inline Content
</div>
```

Here's the JS, I don't know what's causing the issue

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var essapi_9;
essapi_9 = jQuery("#esg-grid-9-1").tpessential({
    gridID: 9,
    layout: "masonry",
    forceFullWidth: "off",
    lazyLoad: "off",
    row: 2,
    loadMoreAjaxToken: "7ac9dc1f8a",
    loadMoreAjaxUrl: "",
    loadMoreAjaxAction: "Essential_Grid_Front_request_ajax",
    ajaxContentTarget: "ess-grid-ajax-container-",
    ajaxScrollToOffset: "0",
    ajaxCloseButton: "off",
    ajaxContentSliding: "on",
    ajaxScrollToOnLoad: "on",
    ajaxNavButton: "off",
    ajaxCloseType: "type1",
    ajaxCloseInner: "false",
    ajaxCloseStyle: "light",
    ajaxClosePosition: "tr",
    space: 30,
    pageAnimation: "fade",
    paginationScrollToTop: "off",
    spinner: "spinner0",
    lightBoxMode: "single",
    animSpeed: 1000,
    delayBasic: 1,
    mainhoverdelay: 1,
    filterType: "single",
    showDropFilter: "hover",
    filterGroupClass: "esg-fgc-9",
    googleFonts: ['Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800', 'Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900', 'Droid+Serif:400,700'],
    responsiveEntries: [{
        width: 1400,
        amount: 3
    }, {
        width: 1170,
        amount: 3
    }, {
        width: 1024,
        amount: 3
    }, {
        width: 960,
        amount: 3
    }, {
        width: 778,
        amount: 2
    }, {
        width: 640,
        amount: 2
    }, {
        width: 480,
        amount: 1
    }]
});

try {
    jQuery("#esg-grid-9-1 .esgbox").esgbox({


    });

} catch (e) {}


});
```

Comment: Any error in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but no error on console.

Comment: Could you add `console.log(e.message);` inside the `catch` block ?

Comment: Hi, What is "esgbox" (from there - `jQuery("#esg-grid-9-1 .esgbox").esgbox()`)?